# How do I compare the skewness and kurtosis of different histograms?

Tags: skewness, histogram, kurtosis, barplot

I have generated histograms from each of the succeeding years. I thought of plotting the skewness and kurtosis of each to compare them. I am not sure if a qualitative description suffices to show their differences. Is it possible to do hypothesis testing to compare the measures of shape between histograms (e.g. skewness and kurtosis)? If it is, what is the suitable method to do a proper statistical analysis for this sort of data sets?

[image: Histograms of scores from each year of 2009-2015; the last graph is a plot of skewness and kurtosis of each histogram]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to compare the performance of laboratories participating in an external quality assessment through the distribution of scores for each year

Comment: 1. Why would a calculation of skewness or kurtosis be useful for "comparing performance"? ... 2. Do you have the original data or only the counts in each histogram bin?

Comment: 1. I want to show that over time, a lot of participants were getting similar high scores. 2. I have the original data.